# How can I get a list of all active enabled contexts on drupal site with drush?

Tags: drush

I can list all enabled modules by calling `drush pml`.

I can also used flags to only return certain kinds of modules, based on where they are enabled or not and so on:

```
Show a list of available extensions (modules and themes).

Options:
 --type                                    Filter by extension type. Choices: module, theme.                                                        
 --status                                  Filter by extension status. Choices: enabled, disable and/or 'not installed'. You can use multiple comma 
                                           separated values. (i.e. --status="disabled,not installed").                                              
 --package                                 Filter by project packages. You can use multiple comma separated values. (i.e. --package="Core -         
                                           required,Other").                                                                                        
 --core                                    Filter out extensions that are not in drupal core.                                                       
 --no-core                                 Filter out extensions that are provided by drupal core.                                                  
 --pipe                                    Returns a space delimited list of the names of the resulting extensions.
```

How can I list all the contexts enabled on a site in a similar fashion, so I can rype something like `drush context-list`

Answer (score 2):

i would say something like this:

```
drush php-eval "print_r(context_active_contexts());"
```